# Passing a new command to a Powershell Elevated instance using schtasks.exe in python using subprocess.run

Tags: python, powershell, subprocess

I'm trying to execute dynamically some powershell commands that require admin priviledges in my python application.
But I'm facing problems to obtain the behaviour I want when stacking commands with **subprocess.run**
So let's discuss the code:
This is an example command that requires admin priviledges(elevated prompt) to be run:

```py
import subprocess
admin_cmd = r'New-NetFirewallRule -DisplayName "Notepad block -Outbound-" -Direction Outbound -Program "C:\Windows\System32\notepad.exe" -Action Block'
subprocess.run(["powershell.exe", "-Command", admin_cmd])
```

This command will output an error:
**New-NetFirewallRule : Accesso negato.**
[image]
Obviously it runs without a problem in a elevated powershell.
So as a solution I created a task to bypass UAC and run an elevated powershell without workflow interruption.
I can run the elevated shell like this:
`subprocess.run(['schtasks.exe', "/run", "/tn", "Powershell_Elevata"])`

Or like this:
`subprocess.run(["powershell.exe", "-Command", r'Start-Process schtasks.exe -ArgumentList "/run /tn Powershell_elevata"'])`
But if i try to pipe **admin_cmd** with -c or -Command, with any of those I will get an error
cause schtasks.exe knows nothing about New-NetFirewallRule.

So how do I fix the problem? Possibly without the need of creating new files, just python code.
And if possible the Elevated Powershell should run the example command silently without opening a window.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your intent is to pass PowerShells command *ad hoc* to an open-ended scheduled task that runs an interactive, elevated PowerShell session.

- Defining such a task is a security risk, as it effectively bypasses UAC.
- You cannot pass arguments or pipe data to a scheduled task *on invocation*.

  - Any arguments have to be *part of the scheduled task itself*, as part of an action definition.
  - While you could hypothetically *modify* the scheduled task with the arguments at hand before every invocation, using PowerShell's [`Set-ScheduledTask`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/scheduledtasks/set-scheduledtask) cmdlet, for instance, doing so *requires elevation* / entering your password if the task is configured to run with elevation, which defeats the purpose for you.

---

If you have to bypass UAC at all - which is always a security concern - it is best to do it for *select commands only*, which would mean defining your `Powershell_Elevata` task (possibly under a more specific name) with the specific `New-NetFirewallRule` call "baked in", i.e. as part of the task's action.

If you need ad-hoc parameterization of the `New-NetFirewallRule` command, you'd have to save the dynamic values to a *file* and have the PowerShell command in the scheduled task read that file.

Comment: And what the format should be?
This would work?
schtasks /run /tn "NOME_TASK" /parameter1 valore1 /parameter2 valore2
Where NOME_TASK is the task that runs the ps1 file and args inside are used like $args[0], $args[1]? Or should they have to be $parameter1 and $parameter2?

Comment: @Relok, it looks like you misread my answer: it explains that you cannot pass arguments to a scheduled task on invocation. Any arguments have to be an - invariably _static_ - part of the task definition itself.

Comment: So basically those parameters should be baked into the tasks themselves. Meaning I have to necessarily create multiple tasks to handle it. It will work, despite it's not what I wanted, but I understand the security reasons.

Comment: @Relok, I definitely wouldn't recommend it for security reasons, but you could designate a `.ps1` file to which you save commands before every invocation and have the command baked into the task execute that file.